# Can not run kafka+sonar in same docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, sonarqube

I'm trying to run a docker-compose with Kafka and Sonar to run my tests and get its coverage, but they can not run in parallel and I could not find the reason.

If I move them to different docker-compose files, run the sonar one and wait it be up, right after run the kafka one, I can see in the sonar log:

```
sonarqube_1  | 2021.03.07 12:06:43 WARN  app[][o.s.a.p.AbstractManagedProcess] Process exited with exit value [es]: 137
sonarqube_1  | 2021.03.07 12:06:43 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[es] is stopped
sonarqube_1  | 2021.03.07 12:06:43 INFO  ce[][o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint] Hard stopping process
```

Here is my docker-compose:

```
version: '2.1'
services:

  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:5.5.1
    hostname: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000

  broker:
    image: confluentinc/cp-server:5.5.1
    hostname: broker
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_METRIC_REPORTERS: io.confluent.metrics.reporter.ConfluentMetricsReporter
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_LICENSE_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_LOG_RETENTION_MS: 1000
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: broker:29092
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_TOPIC_REPLICAS: 1
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_ENABLE: 'true'
      CONFLUENT_SUPPORT_CUSTOMER_ID: 'anonymous'

  sonarqube:
    image: sonarqube
    expose:
      - 9000
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:9000:9000"
    networks:
      - sonarnet
    environment:
      - SONARQUBE_JDBC_URL=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/sonar
      - SONARQUBE_JDBC_USERNAME=sonar
      - SONARQUBE_JDBC_PASSWORD=sonar
    volumes:
      - sonarqube_conf:/opt/sonarqube/conf
      - sonarqube_data:/opt/sonarqube/data
      - sonarqube_extensions:/opt/sonarqube/extensions
      - sonarqube_bundled-plugins:/opt/sonarqube/lib/bundled-plugins

  db:
    image: postgres
    networks:
      - sonarnet
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=sonar
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=sonar
    volumes:
      - postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql
      - postgresql_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

networks:
  sonarnet:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  sonarqube_conf:
  sonarqube_data:
  sonarqube_extensions:
  sonarqube_bundled-plugins:
  postgresql:
  postgresql_data:
```

Comment: Probably it is about your volumes. If there is nothing important inside them, clean and restart. I copied scenario and worked fine for me.

Comment: Removed Kafka tag because no config or code was shown to indicate that Kafka is causing the problem

Comment: Removing the volumes still not working, sonar just stop.